# Discord bot "gateaway" crash - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**Hey there**
I need some help, two days ago my discord bot started crashing randomly.
The error that I'm facing is:

```
    events.js:367
    throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (ErrorEvent {
  target: WebSocket {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      message: [Function],
      open: [Function],
      error: [Function],
      close: [Function]
    },
    _eventsCount: 4,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    readyState: 2,
    protocol: '',
    _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
    _closeFrameReceived: false,
    _closeFrameSent: false,
    _closeMessage: '',
    _closeTimer: null,
    _closeCode: 1006,
    _extensions: {},
    _receiver: null,
    _sender: null,
    _socket: null,
    _isServer: false,
    _redirects: 0,
    url: 'wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json',
    _req: null,
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  type: 'error',
  message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 162.159.130.234:443',
  error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 162.159.130.234:443
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
    errno: -4039,
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '162.159.130.234',
    port: 443
  }
})
    at Client.emit (events.js:365:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.onError (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\app\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:377:17)
    at WebSocket.onError (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\app\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:128:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\app\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:568:15)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3) {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR',
  context: ErrorEvent {
    target: WebSocket {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        message: [Function: onMessage] { _listener: [Function: bound onMessage] },
        open: [Function: onOpen] { _listener: [Function: bound onOpen] },
        error: [Function: onError] { _listener: [Function: bound onError] },
        close: [Function: onClose] { _listener: [Function: bound onClose] }
      },
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      readyState: 2,
      protocol: '',
      _binaryType: 'nodebuffer',
      _closeFrameReceived: false,
      _closeFrameSent: false,
      _closeMessage: '',
      _closeTimer: null,
      _closeCode: 1006,
      _extensions: {},
      _receiver: null,
      _sender: null,
      _socket: null,
      _isServer: false,
      _redirects: 0,
      url: 'wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=6&encoding=json',
      _req: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    type: 'error',
    message: 'connect ETIMEDOUT 162.159.130.234:443',
    error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 162.159.130.234:443
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
      errno: -4039,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '162.159.130.234',
      port: 443
    }
  }
}
```

**It's crashing my app all day, sometimes after 2 hours of usage, sometimes after 6 hours of usage.**
I think it's something related to the gateaway, so I tried several things like removing the internet connection to the machine to see if it crashes the same way, but it doesn't. Already rewrote my code several times, really don't know where the issue is.
Obs: I already tried to update discord.js, didn't fix it.

Comment: What is your code? Where is it crashing?

Comment: It's not crashing when running a command, it's crashing randomly like without me doing anything. It runs for like hours and then crash.

Comment: Looks like a network issue on your side.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like network issue, if you want auto restart boy after it crashed, you can use Pm2, a multifunction process manager, link: https://discordjs.guide/improving-dev-environment/pm2.html